# android studio parse and highlight text, numbers, dates and show them by blocks

Tags: android, listview, kotlin, view, selection

In my app, I want to parse text via Regex (it's clear) and devide content by text, numbers, and dates then add devided blocks (TextView?) to view and highlight them (+ make them clikable), but don't know which components/views to use, because I need to determine width or/and constrains

here's I make it manual in paint:
[image: here's I make it manual in paint]

Comment: thank you! I tried it just now, for selection it's brilliant, but how can I make parts of one TextView clicable, it's one component, while I want few, present nicely in a view. e.g. LinearLayout not good for this task, do we have other options?

Comment: You can use constraint layout and put textviews next to each other. You can make textviews clickable or unclickable.

Comment: I tried this, https://i.ibb.co/h28nd1b/image.png how am I supposed to determine text width? calculate it after each addition and rebind - only soution we have? Secondly Text can start from the middle and make few lines, it's impossible to have one TextView for this, how to determine how many words will go for the first part (from middle to the end of string)? looking for ready-to-go component which will do it for me out of the box, is it exist?

Comment: You can give weight to your edittexts and you can set number of characters in one edittext.

Comment: yeah but how calculate width of one character? I is thinner than W, by weight your meant LinearLayour?

Comment: When you have several textviews in a layout, you set weight for them so that sum of them is equal to layout weight. You don't need to calculate width of characters

Comment: which layout type do u use for that? tried few, I calculated weight as string length, for 2 TextViews, layout weight as sum of them, didn't work - the same result as previous screen

Comment: You should use textwatcher to see what is in input. Then you can change color of numbers with help of answer of this question: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59628149/how-can-we-have-searched-characters-colored-when-we-use-searchview-in-recyclervi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59628149/how-can-we-have-searched-characters-colored-when-we-use-searchview-in-recyclervi) For using textwatcher see my answer for this question: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60839902/dynamic-leading-text-for-androids-edittext/60843248#60843248](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60839902/dynamic-le

Comment: highlighting works as I mention, text won't change, didn't get the point why do I need to watch it for change. I'm gonna have many text views, the question is how to put them in view to make it good looking like img in question

Comment: SOLUTION: finally resolved by https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout